# Cant find issue in my code

Tags: c#, file-listing

I'm trying to write a program which will list directory and show files?subdirectories and files extension. 
But somewhere in my code, I have an issue. I load files and directories successfully, but when i try to write files types i can't do this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        string dir, mask;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter file mask:");
        mask = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter directory:");
        dir = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No such directory");
            Console.Read();
        }
        else
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*" + mask + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)            

            string[] files_types = new string[files.Length];
            int file_i, type_i;
            for (file_i = 0; file_i == files.Length;file_i++)
            {
                string curr_file = files[file_i];
                string f_type = "";

                {
                    for (type_i = 0; type_i == curr_file.Length; type_i++)
                    {
                        if (curr_file[type_i].ToString() == ".")
                        {
                            int dot_place;

                            for (dot_place = type_i; dot_place == curr_file.Length; dot_place++)
                            {
                                f_type += curr_file[dot_place].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    files_types[file_i] = f_type;
                }
            }

            for (i=0;i==files.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("========================FILES=======================");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i == folders.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("========================FOLDERS=======================");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i == files_types.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("========================TYPES=======================");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand where.

Comment: Please be more specific on your problem. Do you get an error? Exception? Unexecpected results? Also "Cant find issue in my code" is a really bad title, as it doesn´t contain *any* useful information. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when you write "types", do you want to see just the extension, like "PDF", "EXE", "CSPROJ" => go for `System.IO.Path.GetExtension()`, or would you expect a friendly description of the filetype? The current implementation scanning for the first dot is flawed because in modern filesystems, there can be multiple dots in a file name.

Comment: `for (file_i = 0; file_i == files.Length;file_i++)` do you even enter this loop? It is very unlikely if `files` contains anything. Feels like you used `==` instead of `<` in all your loops. In C#, the middle statement is a ***continue*** condition, not a ***break*** condition

Comment: Not only has Path the method GetExtension, but you are also missing all the good stuff string has to offer, like : [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) , [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) and many more ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just have a look at this line:

```
for (file_i = 0; file_i == files.Length; file_i++)
// --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In C#, the condition I underlined with `^`s is a **continue** condition, not a **break** condition.

You most likely meant:

```
for (file_i = 0; file_i < files.Length; file_i++)
// ---------------------^
```

This stands for all of your `for` loops.

---

```
for (file_i = 0; file_i == files.Length; file_i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

is basically the same as:

```
file_i = 0;
while (file_i == files.Length) // will likely never be entered
{
    // do stuff
    file_i++;
}
```